# How to set props on dynamic created child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Within JSX syntax i can easily set a child prop to follow parent's state, like:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { attr1: 10 } 
    } 
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child prop1={this.state.attr1} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So whenever `state.attr1` changes, Children will have it prop1 changed.
How can i get the same behavior with dynamic created childs:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.buildChildren = (items) => {
            items.map(item => 
                React.createElement(
                    childrenListWithClasses[item['childrenClass']], 
                    { key: item['id'], data: {} }
                )
            )
        }

        this.state = {
            children: buildChildren(this.props.childrenList)
        }

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // maybe here i want to do something like
        nextProps.data.forEach(item => 
            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(item['id']).setProps({ data: item['data']}) )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.state.children}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This piece of code does not work, also i've read that setProps is deprecated. Another approach would be create the child with props ~binded to `this.state.data` if data data is structured as obj:

```
React.createElement(
    childrenListWithClasses[item['childrenClass']], 
        { key: item['id'], data: this.state.data[item['id']] }
    )
```

But seems like it tries to evaluate `this.state.data[item['id']]` at execution.

I've found a suggestion to use cloneWithProps, but this doesn't seem right... If JSX can change child's props why cant i do it with code? also it would not make if i want my child elements to smoothly transition when changing props, child's lifecycle would be ignored.

Comment: might need redux, have you tried redux before or do you not want to use it in general?

Comment: What's the purpose childrenListWithClasses? Can you show us the code?

Comment: @Lau i was trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: @Wijebandara, childrenListWithClasses is a object/hash/dictionary to allow people refering a class/reactComponent with string via config.


` import Example from './example.jsx'

const widgets = {
 'example' : Example
}


export default widgets; `